# How to write Rspec test for running file from command line?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a Ruby project with a UNIX executable file called `parse` located in a `bin` subfolder in my project root directory.
At the moment it's just this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

puts 'hello world'
```

The file can be executed on the command line when this command is run from the project root directory: `bin/parse`

It works fine, but I also want to write a passing Rspec test for it.
I have this spec file:

```
RSpec.describe "end-to-end application behaviour" do
  subject { system('bin/parse') }

  it 'prints the expected messsage to stdout' do
    expect { subject }.to output(
      'hello world'
    ).to_stdout
  end
end
```

When I run it I get the test failure:

> expected block to output "hello world" to stdout, but output nothing

This is the location of my spec file relative to my project root: `spec/integration/parse_spec.rb`

I tried placing `require` and `require_relative` statements in that spec file with the paths to the `parse` executable, in case that would help, but I just kept getting:

> LoadError: cannot load such file

Does anyone know how I can write a test in that file that will pass and prove the `parse` executable behaviour works?

Comment: The system command doesn't return any output. You probably want `\`\`` or `%x()` instead.

Comment: You need to ensure something called from the shell is in the PATH. Otherwise, behavior may change between your specs, lib files, etc. You could try `../../bin/parse` from the spec file, but that will make your code brittle.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs  Thanks, but could you elaborate please? How do I do what you're talking about?  "make sure your parse command is in your PATH"

(I also tried `../../bin/parse` in place of `parse` in your code, but that doesn't work)

(I also had to change your `()` to `{}` because the test failures say it needs blocks)

Comment: You're struggling with an anti-pattern. You'd be better of using let or before blocks to *correctly* (whatever that means for your application) get the output of the command with `%x()` and then do a comparison.

Comment: Include the qualified path to your parse utility in your PATH environment variable. You can set that in the shell, or modify `ENV["PATH"]` inside your program. Using relative paths from your specs will make it unreliable as a test for your real code, so don't do that unless you *really* have to.

Comment: Can you tell me what line of code I need to add to my `parse_spec.rb` file to do this please?
I tried `ENV["PATH"] = './bin/'` but I don't think it worked; I get the same test failure error.
How can I do it by specifying the path relative to the root directory in my project?
The project location of my `parse` utility is `bin/parse`

Comment: Relative paths are sometimes necessary, but in your case this is asking for trouble. Just don't. Put `export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/project/bin"` into your shell, or modify your `ENV["PATH"]` in Ruby to be unambiguous. Getting strangers on the Internet to debug your PATH is going to be an excerise in frustration, and it's hard to see how it adds value to your tests or your program.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't Use the RSpec Output Matcher

RSpec has a built-in [output matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-9/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher) than can test both *where* output goes, as well as its contents. However, it's testing where your *Ruby* output goes, not whether some external application is using standard input or standard error. You're going to have to make some different assumptions about your code.

You can avoid driving yourself nuts by comparing *strings* rather than testing the underlying shell or your output streams. For example, consider:

```rb
RSpec.describe "parse utility output" do
  it "prints the right string on standard output" do
    expect(`echo hello world`).to start_with("hello world")
  end

  it "shows nothing on standard output when it prints to stderr" do
    expect(`echo foo >&2 > /dev/null`).to be_empty
  end
end
```

Just replace the echo statements with the correct invocation of `parse` for your system, perhaps by setting PATH directly in your shell, using a utility like [direnv](https://direnv.net/), or by modifying `ENV["PATH"]` in your spec or spec_helper.

As a rule of thumb, RSpec isn't really meant for testing command-line applications. If you want to do that, consider using the [Aruba framework](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba) to exercise your command-line applications. It's best to use RSpec to test the results of methods or the output of commands, rather than trying to test basic functionality. Of course, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Use ‍`to_stdout_from_any_process` instead of `to_stdout`:

```
expect { subject }.to output('hello world').to_stdout_from_any_process
```